# ios : NSArray of CFUUIDRef

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to use CoreBluetooth's retrievePeripheral :

```
- (void)retrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripheralUUIDs;
```

The documentation says peripheralUUIDs should be a NSArray of CFUUIDRef. In the Apple sample project temperatureSensor, it is called as :

```
[centralManager retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)uuid]];
```

(uuid being a CFUUIDRef)
When I use the exact same code in XCode 4.5.1, IOS6, I'm getting a error :

> Cast of C pointer type 'CFUUIDRef' (aka 'const struct __CFUUID *') to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast

I would say (though I'm far from sure) that the reason it works in TemperatureSensor and not in my project is because TemperatureSensor seems not to use ARC whereas my project does.

Xcode suggests 2 ways of solving the problem : adding a `__bridge` or using `CFBridgingRelease().` I tried them both and I'm under the impression that the function does not work [Edit] because the delegate methode didRetrievePeripheral: never gets called [/Edit] (my understanding is that these operation would change the C-style structs into objective-C-objects thus creating a `NSUUID`, and the method can't use it, but, again I'm really not sure)

So what should I do ? I've been searching on google for examples of retrievePeripherals using ARC, but without success.

Comment: What makes you think it is not working?  Everything was bridged before so the semantics have not changed, it was just more automatic than it is now.

Comment: It feels like it's not working because the didRetrievePeripheral: delegate method never gets called... (but maybe my diagnose is false)

Comment: (turns out it was false indeed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was much simpler than that. I copied/pasted some code from TemperatureSensor, specifically the DidRetrievePeripheral. But it turns out, there's an error in this code (it's DidRetrievePeripheralS), so the delegate method never gets called. I think the bug is already reported.

Thanks/sorry

Comment: Wow, this answer surely will save me about 5 hours of debug time! Thanks, Joachim!

Answer (score 2):

In the temperature sensor change this line and run

`LeDiscovery.m`

```
 -(void) startScanningForUUIDString:(NSString *)uuidString
 {
      [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:0];
 }
```

change the word `nil` and assume 0.

If you want more check this [link](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Category%3aIPhone4SBLEDemo).

I hope its useful for you.